# Lockless serial executor

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm looking for an off-the-shelf lockless serial executor. A serial executor allows concurrent enqueuing of tasks and serial processing of enqueued tasks. I already found [this example](https://github.com/kabutz/javaspecialists/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/javaspecialists/tjsn/concurrency/util/SerialExecutor.java) which looks thread-safe. However, I'm afraid those `synchronized` keywords may cause too much unnecessary contention, especially during enqueuing. The reason I'm asking here for an off-the-shelf one is because writing a thread-safe lockless serial executor myself is far from trivial.

Similar to Spring's example of [ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/handler/ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java), if possible, the lockless serial executor should have at least the following features:

1. an overflow strategy,
2. support for bounded queues.

Maybe, there are alternative names for a "serial executor", which would guide me in my search. That would be helpful too.

Comment: Guava offers `MoreExecutors.newSequentialExecutor(delegate)` and `ExecutionSequencer`, but lack those additional requirements. My personal trick is to chain `CompletableFuture` by keeping the tail reference and use a Semaphore to bound the size. Examples: [PolicyActor](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/simulator/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/simulator/policy/PolicyActor.java), [EventDispatcher](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/jcache/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/jcache/event/EventDispatcher.java).

Comment: What’s the difference between this “serial executor” and a `ThreadPoolExecutor` configured to have exactly one thread?